# How to save customer information using external Api

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api

Can anyone help me on how to save customer information on magento2.
Explanation: I have an external endpoint which comprises customer information(e.g name, address e.t.c) that i need to save on magento2, but i don't know how to go about this.

Any idea/solution will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that should happen repeatedly every X hours, you should create a [CRON job](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/crons/custom-cron-tutorial.html) that calls that external API, gets customer data and updates your database with new/updated data, you can use the [Customer collection/model](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/get-customer-collection-magento-2.html#get-object) to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your external endpoint and code to debug the issue that you are facing. Are you following the Rest or Soap endpoint? For creating customer save information, please follow the guideline:

Although the Magento 2 provides the default customer End point to create an account and also save additional information.

You can use the following code in your model:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
) {
    $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

public function execute()
{
    $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
    $customer->setDob($data['dob'])
             ->setCustomAttribute('custom_attribute',$data['custom_value'])
             ->setName($data['name'])
    $this->_customerRepository->save($customer);
}
```

Use this helper for Magento >2.4.2

```
<?php
```

namespace Company\Customer\Helper;

use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
protected $customerFactory;

```
public function __construct(
    CustomerFactory $customerFactory
) {
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

public function overrideCustomAttribute($pCustomer, $attributeCode, $value)
{
    $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($pCustomer->getId());

    $customerDataModel = $customer->getDataModel();
    $customerDataModel->setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $value);
    $customer->updateData($customerDataModel);
    $customer->save();
}
```

}

Thats it